# Invariant Violation: expected hoisted manifest for ngx-build-plus in yarn install

Tags: angular, yarnpkg, angular15, ngx-build-plus

I have updated angular application to 15 and i try to update ngx-build-plus to 15 but facing below error

> Invariant Violation: expected hoisted manifest for
> "ngx-build-plus#@angular-devkit/build-angular#webpack-dev-server#webpack-dev-middleware#webpack"

I have tried to delete yarn.lock file and package-lock.json file and give yarn install but it not working facing same error.
Tried by uninstall and install that also not working

can help on this issue. how to fix or how to install ngx-build-plus@15 without an error

Answer (score 0):

we just hit the same issue when trying to use Yarn instead odf npm for our projet.
A solution for us was to add some dependencies to the devDependencies part in package.json.

For your issue I'd try to add **@angular-devkit/build-angular** and/or **webpack-dev-server** and/or **webpack-dev-middleware** and/or **webpack**, with the good versions, regarding they're already in your package.json or not

In my case it was

```
"webpack-dev-server": "4.15.0",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "6.1.0"
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment @angular-devkit/build-angular which is already there and i have try to add webpack-dev-server and webpack-dev-middleware i got this below 
error 
An unexpected error occurred: "could not find a copy of webpack-dev-server to link

Comment: Yes, I ended up with the same issue. I had to remove ngx-build-plus that we used to ng serve our projet with instrumentalisation to get code coverage...